# How to extract substring from a blob variable in PL/SQL?

Tags: plsql

I have `v_fileContent blob;`, the value of which is returned by a different procedure, and I need to pass approximately 1000 first characters of it to another procedure. I've googled a lot and have only found ways of getting substrings of various lob type columns in tables. But how is it possible to get a substring of a variable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BLOB to String, SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911460/blob-to-string-sql-server)

Comment: @pix Wouldn't those answers be specific to SQL Server? Seems all the answers are related to a query and not to a variable in a procedure.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a single byte per character encoding (not Unicode) you can use:

[Ask Tom Oracle Source](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:437819871174)

```
utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2( dbms_lob.substr( BLOB_LOCATOR, 1000, 1 ) );
```